# How to store and retrieve ArrayListObject to shared preference in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have and app in which contain listview and adapter. In listview I am storing data in ArrayList and want to store this ArrayList object in sharedpreference and retrieve the same in next activity and populate data in listview. How do I do that?

Code:-

```
listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //here i am adding items to another arraylist
                        List<WhiteListModel> res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
                        WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                        whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());
                        whiteListModel.setPackName(listStorage.get(position).getPackName());
                        whiteListModel.setIcon(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
                        res.add(whiteListModel);

                        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        String json = gson.toJson(res);
                        editor.putString("WhiteList", json);
                        editor.apply();


                        listStorage.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gson to convert your ArrayList into JSON which is in string format and then after you can put that string into shared preference, in next screen you have to make an array list from that JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to implements what you are asking for is by using a library called
Gson, include it in your code like:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

using this, you will be able to convert your array list or any set of data to Json format, store it to Shared Preferences, then Retrieve them.

a simple example to do that is simple and easy to do, [HERE](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/arraylist-in-sharedpreferences/)

Comment: @Niraj then what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@41f0ee50 failed to deserialized json object

Comment: @Niraj try using this way Type listType = new TypeToken<arrayList>() {}.getType();

 
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
List target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass items from one Activity to the other you should use [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Your class `WhiteListModel` should implement `Parcelable` like the documentation suggests you. Then you can do something like this to write the arraylist:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<context>, <targetActivity>);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key", whiteListModel);
```

To get the arraylist you can:

```
whiteListModel = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("key");
```

You can also wrap your model class into another class and make this one parcelable.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in dependencies in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

**UserObj.class**

```
public UserObj {
   String firstName,lastName;

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }   
}
```

save object

```
preferences.putString("user", new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(user));
```

load object

```
String str = preferences.getString("user", "");
if (!str.isEmpty()) {
    user = new GsonBuilder()
           .serializeNulls()
           .create()
           .fromJson(userString, UserObj.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void saveUserLoginDetail(Context context, LoginResponse response) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(response);      
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (preferences != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, jsonString);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

public static LoginResponse getUserLoginDetail(Context mContext) {
    LoginResponse loginResponse = new LoginResponse();
    String jsonString = getStringPreference(mContext, PREF_LOGIN_RESPONSE);
    loginResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, LoginResponse.class);
    return loginResponse;
}
```

> If you want to get back Array List of type any object like LoginResponse then use :

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<LoginResponse>>(){}.getType();
List<LoginResponse> loginResponse= gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data does not require an orderly arrangement and also does not contain duplicate elements.，you can try `SharedPreferences.Editor`#`putStringSet()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Value to List

   ```
              Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
               set.add("11122");
               set.add("222");
   ```
2. Save to shareprefarance set value using  saveSharePrefaraceArrayList method

   ```
   saveSharePrefaraceArrayList(set);
   ```
3. SharedPreference save method to save list of value

   ```
    void saveSharePrefaraceArrayList( Set<String> setList){

       SharedPreferences  prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      Editor edit=prefs.edit();

     Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
      set.addAll(setList);
     edit.putStringSet("myshareprekey", set);
     edit.commit();
    }
   ```
4. Finally get list value from shareprefarance

   ```
   SharedPreferences prefs=this.getSharedPreferences("yourPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor edit=prefs.edit();
   Set<String> set = prefs.getStringSet("myshareprekey", null);
   ArrayList<String> arraylistValues = new ArrayList<String>(set);
   ```

Comment: hey I arraylist how do i put in set

Comment: ArrayList<WhiteListModel> res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
                            WhiteListModel whiteListModel = new WhiteListModel();
                            whiteListModel.setName(listStorage.get(position).getName());

Comment: See my code I want to save ArrayList in Sharepreference